# "group by" proxy model

Tags: c++, qt, viewmodel, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have tree model with theoretically infinite depth and some property "Group".

[image: original view]

In addition to standard view, I need to show this model (and keep it in sync) in such way that each group becomes a virtual parent for all items with the same property value.

[image]

What is the best way to achieve this with Qt's model/view architecture?

I had solved similar problem not a long time ago via inserting additional virtual "groups" on adding/removing items to/from the model, but this method proved not to be very flexible so I'm looking for better solution.

Ideally, I see this implemented via QSortProxyFilter model as for now.

Comment: You will have to implement your own proxy model. Just implement [QAbstractProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractproxymodel.html). It's not a trivial task, but doable. The most important part is to get the index conversions correctly

Comment: How is the data behind your model stored? What is its structure?

Comment: @Felix yeah, that's definitely the way it can be done. Will look into it, thank you.

Comment: @vahancho the data sometimes filled up "by hand" or can be added dynamically by user (or both) and it's basically unordered array of some structs that roughly can be represented as `Item { id: string; name: string; group: int; etc... }`.

Comment: @rsht, I see. I would solve this in the following way: 1) Write a routine that will search all items to get all existing groups 2) The list of groups will represent the top level nodes of your model (not proxy) 3) Model will index child nodes by performing a lookup of items that belong to the given group (parent).

Comment: One important thing is : is the Group belonging mutable or not ? (in other world, can you edit the group of an Item ? )

Comment: @sandwood yes, it's mutable. Moreover, displayed properties of the group (e.g. name) can be changed as well

Comment: Be careful if your source model overrides `hasChildren`, `fetchMore`, as this will by necessity have to visit every node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want as a final result :

- you can achieve the filtering  without having to implement QAbstractProxyModel.

  The QSortFilterProxyModel can sort by Item role , default being Qt::DisplayRole. But if you put your group property in a custom Role of your item, then you can sort by this custom role : cf :
  https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#sortRole-prop

  That should do the main job of sorting for the specific view ordered by Group.

  But you won't have "collapsable group" node. hard to say if you can manage to equivalent feature with a custom renderer.
- Otherwise, the hard way, as suggested by Felix, implement your custom QAbstractProxyModel that will create node group indexes.
- Last solution : create your own (base) model (something like MyTree and `Map<Group,Node>` ,  and two Qt models (one for each view)). Update both models via Qt's signal/slot mecanism when your base model is updated and vice versa.

Comment: `QSortFilterProxyModel` is not a good fit for changes in shape, which is what this would be. Note the source model is tree-like

Comment: dit it via QAbstractProxyModel. Thanks!

Comment: @rsht do you care to share you solution.  I'm trying to do this same thing right now

Comment: @JokerMartini I do, but I can not because of my agreement with company I worked for while implementing this. Basically, you would need to implement your own QAbstractProxyModel which would add virtual parents for every item from source model. Add this virtual parents, if they do not exist, on rowsInserted and remove them on rowsRemoved(you would need put them into "remove queue" on rowsAboutToBeRemoved, and then execute actual removal on rowsRemoved). The hard part for me was figuring out how to map source index to your index (see QModelIndex::internalId).

Comment: @JokerMartini everything else should be trivial(implement every other pure virtual method by converting index with mapFromSource() and forwarding it). Let me know if you need any other hints on this, I would be happy to help.

Comment: @JokerMartini other important thing is that I've implemented this only for lists and I'm converting tree models to lists with KDescendantsProxyModel (open source, look it up). So, if you would need it to work with tree-like models without using mentioned proxy model - you might face some problems that I'm not aware of.