# QTreeView GroupBy Dict Key

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

What would be a flexible and good approach to making it so when a user clicks the GroupBy Key it uses the clicked action to group the items in my treeview like the before and after pictures seen below?

I see this feature in so many TreeView like applications but it doesn't appear that pyside has a build in solution for grouping unlike C#.

[image]

```
import os, sys, re
sys.path.append(os.environ.get('PS_SITEPACKAGES'))
from Qt import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore

items = [
    {'sex': 'male', 'age': 32, 'name': 'Kevin', 'color': 'green'},
    {'sex': 'male', 'age': 60, 'name': 'Michell', 'color': 'blue'},
    {'sex': 'female', 'age': 32, 'name': 'Amy', 'color': 'blue'},
    {'sex': 'male', 'age': 24, 'name': 'Katie', 'color': 'green'},
    {'sex': 'female', 'age': 16, 'name': 'Amanda', 'color': 'orange'},
    {'sex': 'female', 'age': 16, 'name': 'Jesse', 'color': 'yellow'},
    {'sex': 'female', 'age': 60, 'name': 'Cory', 'color': 'green'},
]

class CategoryView(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self)
        self.resize(400,400)
        self.createMenus()

        self.itemModel = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()

        self.proxyModel = QtCore.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxyModel.setSourceModel(self.itemModel)

        self.uiTreeView = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.uiTreeView.setModel(self.proxyModel)
        self.uiTreeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.uiTreeView.sortByColumn(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.uiTreeView.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.uiTreeView.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.uiTreeView.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.uiTreeView.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.uiTreeView)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.uiTreeView.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.slotOpenContextMenu)

        self.populate()


    def populate(self):
        self.itemModel.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Name', 'Age', 'Color'])
        parentItem = self.itemModel.invisibleRootItem()
        for x in items:
            c1 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(x.get('sex')))
            c2 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(x.get('age')))
            c3 = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(x.get('color')))
            parentItem.appendRow([c1,c2,c3])

    def createMenus(self):
        self.contextMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu('File', self)
        self.groupByMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu('Group By', self)
        self.contextMenu.addMenu(self.groupByMenu)

        keys = items[0].keys()
        for x in keys:
            act = QtWidgets.QAction(x, self)
            act.triggered.connect(self.clickedGroupByKey)
            self.groupByMenu.addAction(act)

    # Slots
    def slotOpenContextMenu(self):
        self.contextMenu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())


    def clickedGroupByKey(self):
        print self.sender()

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CategoryView()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
    main()
```

Comment: What built in grouping solution of C# are you referring to? This sounds like an entirely application specific feature to me.

Comment: Simply search 'listview groups in .net"

Comment: I figured this would be done by subclassing Q standard item model. However I don't even know how to subclass that and create a model that supports children in a treeview. I've only used subclasses of the item model to do flat lists or tables

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49759442/group-by-proxy-model